# CORS problem with interaction between server and client: Go + JS

Tags: javascript, go, cors

I’m making simple web application of uploading the products. I have a server on GO, which has only one handler on POST method. I have some demontsration below:

```golang
package main

import (
 "encoding/json"
 "fmt"
 "github.com/gorilla/mux"
 "net/http"
)

type Product struct {
 Id int json:"id"
 Desc string json:"desc"
}

func productsPostHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
 p := &Product{}
 json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(p)
 fmt.Println(p.Id, p.Desc)
}

func main() {
 router := mux.NewRouter()
 router.HandleFunc("/products", productsPostHandler).Methods("POST")
 fmt.Println("Server is listening...")
 http.ListenAndServe(":8181", router)
}
```

And also, I have js client, a simple query to my server. I'm trying to upload the specific Product:

```
fetch("http://localhost:8181/products", {
 method: "POST",
 body: JSON.stringify({
 id: 1,
 desc: "The first product",
 })
 })
 .then(response => {
 console.log(response)
 })
```

When server and client try to interact, it failed with the CORS error below.

I want to avoid this error. I guess, I got to fix the http headers in the request somehow. I’ve tried to add the “Access-Allow-Origin” and nothing happened. So, I’m asking for your help.

Comment: `I got to fix the http headers in the request somehow` not quite - you need to add CORS headers in the *response* from the server side.

Comment: See https://github.com/jub0bs/fcors-examples/blob/main/gorilla-mux/main.go

Comment: What is the Web origin of your client? What CORS error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

See my Code Example below. This [package](https://github.com/rs/cors) will help you set up CORS in your Golang application.

from [package](https://github.com/rs/cors):

```golang
c := cors.New(cors.Options{
    AllowedOrigins: []string{"http://foo.io", "http://foo.io:8080"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
    // Enable Debugging for testing, consider disabling in production
    Debug: true,
})

// Insert the middleware
handler = c.Handler(handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set CORS headers in your server response. CORS is a way for servers to set the kinds of headers, methods and allowed domains for a client, usually with a Pre-Flight request.

[A good introduction to setting CORS headers](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2023/introduction-to-cors-for-go-programmers/)

You can also use the package recommended by Pranjal

For more info on CORS try MDN docs
[What is CORS?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)